# Errors encountered during job execution. Unexpected. Please try again

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running a simple query which reads from a five-column table with five million rows and copies it to a new table adding an extra constant column.

This query keeps on failing with the following message:

```
u'status': {u'errorResult': {u'message': u'Unexpected. Please try again.',
u'reason': u'internalError'},
u'errors': [{u'message': u'Unexpected. Please try again.',
u'reason': u'internalError'}],
u'state': u'DONE'}}
```

Checking the jobs in [BigQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigQuery) I get:

> Errors encountered during job execution. Unexpected. Please try again.

The following jobIds had this problem:

job_6eae11c7792446a1b600fe5554071d32   query      FAILURE   02 Aug 09:46:04   0:01:00
  job_92ff013841574399a459e8c4296d7c73   query      FAILURE   02 Aug 09:45:10   0:00:49
  job_a1a11ee7bbec4c08b5e58b91b27aafad   query      FAILURE   02 Aug 09:43:40   0:00:55
  job_496f8af99da94d8292f90580f73af64e   query      FAILURE   02 Aug 09:42:46   0:00:51

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug with large result sets ... we've got a fix and will release it today.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, I've tested it right now and the error is gone :-)

Comment: We still see this issue. (JobID:job_3bded2d8d7de421cb8f77e21208f8a45

Comment: I've got a similar issue with job_HGe-HdIXwEfL_gviOFhlcp5TqiQ

Comment: This job did not set allowLargeResults.

Comment: Can you please check job_V6CzbipQZLyr2U_Rhm5Ce1QUuIY ? allowLargeResults was set but it's still failing.